# How to shrink content to fit a frame?

Tags: beamer, bibtex

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetheme{Madrid}


\algnewcommand\algorithmicinput{\textbf{Input:}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicoutput{\textbf{Output:}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicinitialization{\textbf{Initialize:}}
\algnewcommand\Input{\item[\algorithmicinput]}%
\algnewcommand\Output{\item[\algorithmicoutput]}%
\algnewcommand\Initialize{\item[\algorithmicinitialization]}%


\logo{%
  \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}%
  \hspace{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2cm-5pt}%
  \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}%
}
\begin{document}
  \title{Resource  Allocation in Cloud Radio Access Network}
  \author[Md.Al-Helal \& Jobayed Ullah]{
  \parbox{2.5cm}{
\centering Md.Al-Helal\\Roll:SH-51}\hspace{1cm}
\parbox{2.5cm}{
{\centering Jobayed Ullah\\Roll:EK-107}}
\centering \vspace{1cm}\\Supervisor:\\Tomal Adhikary
}

\vspace{1cm}
\institute[CSEDU]{Computer Science \& Engineering\\CSEDU}
\date{February 25, 2018}
\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Background}
  Traditional cellular, or Radio Access Networks (RAN), consist of many standalone base stations (BTS) have some limitations-
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Each BTS is costly to build and operate.
    \item When more BTS are added to a system to improve its capacity, interference among BTS is more severe as BTS are closer to each other.
    \item Because users are mobile, the traffic of each BTS fluctuates (called 'tide effect'), and as a result, the average utilization rate of individual BTS is pretty low.
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Motivation}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item As one of the promising evolution paths for future cellular network architecture, C-RAN has attracted high academic research interest.
    \item Meanwhile, because the native support of cooperative radio capability built into the C-RAN architecture, it also enables many advanced algorithms that were hard to implement in cellular networks, including Cooperative Multi-Point Transmission/Receiving, Network Coding, etc.
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Architechture Overview\cite{journals/corr/PengSLMW16}}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-a}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Architechture Overview\cite{wiki:C-RAN}}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Large scale centralized deployment: Allows hundreds of thousands of RRHs to connect to a centralized BBU pool.
    \item Native support to Collaborative Radio technologies: Any BBU can talk with any other BBU within the BBU pool with very high bandwidth (10Gbit/s and above) and low latency(10us level).
    \item  C-RAN BBU pool is built on open hardware, like x86/ARM CPU based servers. Real-time virtualization makes sure the resources in the pool can be allocated dynamically to base station software stacks, say 4G/3G/2G function modules from different vendors according to network load.
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Related Work}
  In\cite{journals/twc/TangTQ15},they propose and investigate a cross-layer resource allocation model for C-RAN to minimize the overall system power consumption in the BBU pool, fiber links and the remote radio heads (RRHs). They characterize the cross-layer resource allocation problem as a mixed-integer nonlinear programming (MINLP), which jointly considers elastic service scaling, RRH selection, and joint beamforming.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Related Work}
  In\cite{conf/wiopt/AlabbasiC17} they analyze the delay performance of the end user’s request. They propose an end-to-end (from the central cloud to the end user) delay model (per user’s request) for different function split points. In that model, different delay requirements enforce different function splits, hence affect the system’s energy consumption. Therefore, they proposed several research directions to incorporate the proposed delay model in the problem of minimizing energy and bandwidth consumption in the network.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{References}
  \bibliography{references}
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{\phantom{}}
 % \color{Brown}
  \color{Sepia}
  \centering \Huge\textbf{Thank You}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

`references.bib`

```
@Article{journals/corr/PengSLMW16,
  title =   "Recent Advances in Cloud Radio Access Networks: System
         Architectures, Key Techniques, and Open Issues",
  author =  "Mugen Peng and Yaohua Sun and Xuelong Li and Zhendong
         Mao and Chonggang Wang",
  journal = "CoRR",
  year =    "2016",
  volume =  "abs/1604.00607",
  bibdate = "2017-06-07",
  bibsource =   "DBLP,
         http://dblp.uni-trier.de/db/journals/corr/corr1604.html#PengSLMW16",
  URL =     "http://arxiv.org/abs/1604.00607",
}


@Article{journals/twc/TangTQ15,
  title =   "Cross-Layer Resource Allocation With Elastic Service
         Scaling in Cloud Radio Access Network",
  author =  "Jianhua Tang and Wee-Peng Tay and Tony Q. S. Quek",
  journal = "IEEE Trans. Wireless Communications",
  year =    "2015",
  number =  "9",
  volume =  "14",
  bibdate = "2017-06-09",
  bibsource =   "DBLP,
         http://dblp.uni-trier.de/https://doi.org/10.1109/TWC.2015.2432023;
         DBLP,
         http://dblp.uni-trier.de/db/journals/twc/twc14.html#TangTQ15",
  pages =   "5068--5081",
}


@InProceedings{conf/wiopt/AlabbasiC17,
  title =   "Delay-aware green hybrid CRAN",
  author =  "Abdulrahman Alabbasi and Cicek Cavdar",
  publisher =   "IEEE",
  year =    "2017",
  bibdate = "2017-07-06",
  bibsource =   "DBLP,
         http://dblp.uni-trier.de/https://doi.org/10.23919/WIOPT.2017.7959942;
         DBLP,
         http://dblp.uni-trier.de/db/conf/wiopt/wiopt2017.html#AlabbasiC17",
  booktitle =   "WiOpt",
  crossref =    "conf/wiopt/2017",
  ISBN =    "978-3-9018-8290-6",
  pages =   "1--7",
  URL =     "http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/mostRecentIssue.jsp?punumber=7951216",
}
@misc{wiki:C-RAN,
   author = "Wikipedia",
   title = "{C-RAN} --- {W}ikipedia{,} The Free Encyclopedia",
   year = "2018",
   howpublished = {\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=C-RAN&oldid=827881004}},
   note = "[Online; accessed 26-March-2018]"
 }
```

For the above code I get

[image]

Where the last reference about to go to out of the frame. How can I shrink(set a height) the content in height so that they fit in frame?

Comment: please have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4408/36296 This would make answering your questions a lot easier.

Comment: Don't shrink the content, but choose a smaller font size

Comment: off-topic, but you don't need `xcolor` with beamer

Comment: @samcarter But, using the MWEB results error. see this https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tMKXwX5p84/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose a smaller font:

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{journals/corr/PengSLMW16,
  title =   "Recent Advances in Cloud Radio Access Networks: System
         Architectures, Key Techniques, and Open Issues",
  author =  "Mugen Peng and Yaohua Sun and Xuelong Li and Zhendong
         Mao and Chonggang Wang",
  journal = "CoRR",
  year =    "2016",
  volume =  "abs/1604.00607",
  bibdate = "2017-06-07",
  bibsource =   "DBLP,
         http://dblp.uni-trier.de/db/journals/corr/corr1604.html#PengSLMW16",
  URL =     "http://arxiv.org/abs/1604.00607",
}


@Article{journals/twc/TangTQ15,
  title =   "Cross-Layer Resource Allocation With Elastic Service
         Scaling in Cloud Radio Access Network",
  author =  "Jianhua Tang and Wee-Peng Tay and Tony Q. S. Quek",
  journal = "IEEE Trans. Wireless Communications",
  year =    "2015",
  number =  "9",
  volume =  "14",
  bibdate = "2017-06-09",
  bibsource =   "DBLP,
         http://dblp.uni-trier.de/https://doi.org/10.1109/TWC.2015.2432023;
         DBLP,
         http://dblp.uni-trier.de/db/journals/twc/twc14.html#TangTQ15",
  pages =   "5068--5081",
}


@InProceedings{conf/wiopt/AlabbasiC17,
  title =   "Delay-aware green hybrid CRAN",
  author =  "Abdulrahman Alabbasi and Cicek Cavdar",
  publisher =   "IEEE",
  year =    "2017",
  bibdate = "2017-07-06",
  bibsource =   "DBLP,
         http://dblp.uni-trier.de/https://doi.org/10.23919/WIOPT.2017.7959942;
         DBLP,
         http://dblp.uni-trier.de/db/conf/wiopt/wiopt2017.html#AlabbasiC17",
  booktitle =   "WiOpt",
  crossref =    "conf/wiopt/2017",
  ISBN =    "978-3-9018-8290-6",
  pages =   "1--7",
  URL =     "http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/mostRecentIssue.jsp?punumber=7951216",
}
@misc{wiki:C-RAN,
   author = "Wikipedia",
   title = "{C-RAN} --- {W}ikipedia{,} The Free Encyclopedia",
   year = "2018",
   howpublished = {\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=C-RAN&oldid=827881004}},
   note = "[Online; accessed 26-March-2018]"
 }

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{References}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: reference not shown. see this https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/69pw7QjT2w/

Comment: And https://pasteboard.co/HdIcDGE.png

Comment: @alhelal Same as this morning: did you run biber???

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: in my question I didn't use \usepackage `biblatex` but you use. What is better?

Comment: @alhelal The file you linked to had biblatex in it: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tMKXwX5p84/. I did not change it, just threw away unrelated slides to make a minimal working example.